# What is $∩_{ϵ>0}S_ϵ$ when $S_ϵ = [n ∈ N : \sin(n) > 1 − ϵ]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$N$ stands for natural numbers.

So, in the smallest possible case for ϵ (where it is extremely close to 0), wouldn't I have the set of natural numbers where $\sin(n) > $(slightly less than) $1$? Then I'd need $\sin(n) = 1$ for this to work. But since $n$ needs to be irrational for this to happen, then there would be no numbers in the set that would make $\sin(n) >$ (slightly less than) $1$ true, meaning the set is empty, and thus the intersection of *all* sets would be empty as well.

Does this reasoning make sense?

Comment: The general geometric intuition is good, but for any positive $\epsilon$, however small, there are integers $n$ such that $\sin n\gt 1-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the comment of André Nicolas the intersection of these sets is of course empty. For suppose $n \in\cap S_\varepsilon$. Then $\sin(n) = 1-\delta$ for some $\delta >0$. This implies $n\notin S_\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon < \delta$, leading to a contradiction.